# VS 2010 c++ How to have different solution configurations with different source files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have a solution file that has three projects, each with a different solution configuration.  All three solution configurations share a large number of .cpp files, but there are about two .cpp files that differ between the three.  I have three different projects to handle this issue.  Here's an example:

View of the Solution Explorer:

Solution 'Big Project'(3 projects)

Project1

```
Source Files
  foo1
  foo2
  foo3.cpp
  ...
  fooUnique1.cpp
  fooUnique2.cpp
```

Project2

```
Source Files
  foo1.cpp
  foo2.cpp
  foo3.cpp
  ...
  fooUnique3.cpp
  fooUnique4.cpp
```

Project3

```
Source Files
  foo1.cpp
  foo2.cpp
  foo3.cpp
  ...
  fooUnique5.cpp
  fooUnique6.cpp
```

What I would ultimately want is to have just one project and three solution configurations, with each configuration pointing to its respective unique .cpp files.  It is tedious to make a change to a shared .cpp file for each of the projects, so I was wondering if it is possible to have different .cpp files for each solution configuration in one project.

Comment: Can you tell us *why* these files would differ under different solution configs?

Comment: The program has the common files of foo1.cpp, foo2.cpp, etc. located in the project folder, but the unique files are taken from a path that is at a different location for each of the three computers using this program.  The unique files of one computer are of a different version than the unique files on another computer, and they can't all be on the same version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Solution View, select a file, right click on it, and select Properties from the popup menu. On the Properties page for that file, on the General line, you can select "Exclude from build" (yes/no). The answer you select only applies to the active (or otherwise selected) configuration.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative idea, you could setup each solution configuration with a distinct preprocessor define. Then in the relevant files surround the entire contents with ifdefs based on the corresponding defines. That way you can effectively exclude the contents of those files from the configurations you don't want them in. Although the compiler will still see the files in each case, it will skip over anything they contain which is excluded by ifdef.